v62.0 Update has broken Lightning Web Runtime Digital Experience Site
I have created and currently working on a User Portal, which is a Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) Enhanced Experience Cloud site.
This was working fine until Salesforce bumped the version from 61.0 to 62.0 for my dev sandbox. Now I am unable to access the Workspaces or Builder actions. The URL is still accessible directly, but there is no way to edit the site.

Not too sure if this was an unlucky org, as my UAT sandbox that was also bumped to 62.0 works fine. I have heard from others that they've had mixed results with LWR sites when being updated to version 62.0.

Have you contacted Salesforce support? My last experience with support was actually really good, so maybe it's not going to be like pulling teeth.

Looks like the answer is to just wait. A couple hours have passed and the buttons have magically come back. Must be part of the update rollout? Has been about 24hrs since the sandbox had been bumped to 62.0.
